# attach xdf file to pdf with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I have a mind bugging question. Is there a way to attach an xdf file to an existing pdf file with php on the fly ? 
I have generated the pdf and I need to attach it to the pdf file right after the generation of pdf.
Can you help please ?

Answer (score 1):

This may be too late for you, but here is a class that I wrote years ago for CodeIgniter. It can be adjusted to your needs.

```
<?php
class Fdf {

private $ci;
private $db;

private $testing = false; // are we testing?

private $fields = array();
private $pdf_file = '';
private $save_where = array( 'browser' => 'inline' );

public function __construct( $config = array() ){

    $this->ci =& get_instance();

    $this->ci->load->database();

    $this->db =& $this->ci->db;

    if ( $this->testing && $this->CI->config->item('log_threshold') < 2 ){
        $this->ci->config->set_item( 'log_threshold', 2 );
    }

    log_message('debug', 'Fdf class loaded');

}

/**
* This function generates a string in format FDF for use with the indicated pdf form $file.
* $info is an associative array holding the form fields in the key => value form
* $file is the URL of the pdf file that holds the form fields we want to populate
*
* @param mixed $info associative array of the fields
* @param mixed $file URL of the pdf file
*
* @author Alin Mazilu
*/
public function create_fdf_string( $info, $file ){

    $data="%FDF-1.2\n%âãÏÓ\n1 0 obj\n<< \n/FDF << /Fields [ ";

    foreach($info as $field => $val){
        if(is_array($val)){
            $data.='<</T('.$field.')/V[';
            foreach($val as $opt)
                $data.='('.trim($opt).')';
            $data.=']>>';
        }else{
            $data.='<</T('.$field.')/V('.trim($val).')>>';
        }
    }

    $data.="] \n/F (".$file.") /ID [ <".md5(microtime(true)).">\n] >>".
        " \n>> \nendobj\ntrailer\n".
        "<<\n/Root 1 0 R \n\n>>\n%%EOF\n";
    log_message('debug', "FDF string is:\n" . $data);
    return $data;

}

public function set_fields( $data ){

    if (is_object($data)){
        $this->fields = get_object_vars($data);
    } elseif ( is_array($data) ){
        $this->fields = $data;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public function set_pdf_file( $file = '' ){

    if ( empty($file) ){
        return false;
    }

    $this->pdf_file = $file;
    return true;

}

public function set_output( $where ){

    if ( empty( $where ) || !is_array( $where ) ){
        return false;
    }

    $this->save_where = $where;

    return true;

}

public function output( $where = array( 'browser' => 'inline' ) ){

    $str = $this->create_fdf_string( $this->fields, $this->pdf_file );

    $len = strlen( $str );

    if ( empty( $where ) ){
        $where = $this->save_where;
    }

    $file_name = explode( '/', $this->pdf_file );

    $file_name = end( $file_name );



    if ( isset( $where['browser'] ) ){

        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.fdf');
        header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0'); // HTTP/1.1
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
        header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
        header('Content-Disposition: ' . $where['browser'] . '; filename="' . $file_name . '";');
        header('Content-Length: ' . $len);

        echo $str;

    }

}

}
```

The the data is passed in as an associative whose keys are the field names and the values contain the fields' data. The output method is used to dump the FDF file to the browser on the fly. Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I solved this issue in the past. Don't remember quite good how, but found a solution on an obscure forum. Thank you anyway. Really appreciate the effort!

Comment: Can't you retrieve this solution ??

Comment: What do you mean?